# excluding standard library file from code analysis in visual code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

vscode static analyser (clang-tidy based I think) issues me warning on stl files that are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\...`
I tried to exclude them from analysis through this setting:

```json
    "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.exclude": {
        <other excluded dir>,
        "C:/*": true
    }
```

But I still have warnings on stl.
I also tried `"C:\\*"`, `"C:\\**"` and other similar patterns.

Besides, I don't want to silence warning on my own header. I'm working on another drive, thus I tried to exclude all `C:\` but it's probably overkill.

How can I change my settings in order to silence these static analyser warnings?

Comment: try `"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.headerFilter": "${workspaceFolder}"`

Comment: @TooTone your comment made me think I omitted some info. I'll edit my question. Thx